# NPM package cannot be used as a JSX Component - Type errors

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

Ive been getting these strange type errors on my typescript project for certain packages.
Ex:

```
'TimeAgo' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'ReactTimeago<keyof IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<{}>>' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/user/app/node_modules/@types/react-bootstrap-table-next/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

I don't get these type errors on my local windows machine but they keep occurring in my linux virtual machine.  I've deleted the project many times, cloned my repo and installed packages again in different versions of node and I still get the same type errors.

Checked node 12.18.3, 16.13.1

Here is some quick package json info:

```
"react-timeago": "^6.2.1",
"react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
"react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.4.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"next": "^12.1.1",
"@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.10",
"@types/react-timeago": "^4.1.3",
"@types/react": "^17.0.44",
"typescript": "^4.3.5"
"@types/node": "^14.18.12",
```

This happens on basic custom components:

```
MyTst.tsx
import TimeAgo from "react-timeago";

const Mytst = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TimeAgo date={"02/02/2022"} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mytst;
```

I get this error for react-custom-scrollbars-2 as well.  There seems to be an issue with matching the types correctly between the library which contains the component and the @types files associated with them.  Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve these type errors?

Comment: I'm getting similar "TS2786: 'NumberFormat' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'NumberFormat<unknown>' is not a valid JSX element." Do you know if you got this after upgrading to cra v5 or React v18? I'm wondering if that is connected.

Comment: Having similar issues with several 3rd party components used in project. Was not an issue till about 7th April and started to happen recently. Do not know the cause yet.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Had the same issue. Just add this:

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
```

to the `package.json` file and run `yarn` command.

**UPD:** Just a bit detailed answer:

`@types/react-dom` has its own dependencies and one of them is `@types/react` with a version set to `'*'` - a major release, that now, probably refers to `18`.

Even if you specify some strict versions in your `package.json` (without `^`), parent package might install its own duplicates of packages that you are already using for its own purpose.

By using `resolutions`, we are specifying strict restrictions for dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks. Builds had worked locally but not in our CI Alpine container. Looks like some sort of typing version discrepancy may have potentially been pushed to react or related libraries in NPM.

Comment: @BrandonWright see the updated comment, maybe it will help you during your debugging. And if this solution does not work for you:

1. Maybe you are using `npm` instead of `yarn`. NPM is not supporting `resolutions`.

2. Maybe your CI caching versions of downloaded packages and I'm not sure how `resolutions` are cached. You may want to try to clear that cache.

Comment: I had to add the package.json resolution at the root of my Lerna setup for it to work

Comment: By downgrading @types/react version worked for me

"dependencies": {
"@types/react": "^17.0.0",
}

Comment: where did resolution property come from ?! I cannot make it work on heroku.

Comment: not working for me =(

Comment: Is this still up to date ? why would you want a lower typing version than the version of react ?

Comment: to those who are working in turborepo @Stephane's Lerna setup helped me. Add this resolution line in package.json in root of the project.

Answer (score 65):

You will need to fix the version for `@types/react` package because many react libraries have dependency set as `@types/react : "*"`, which will take the latest version of the package. (I suppose they just released version 18)

To do that you can add this in your package.json

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.38"
}
```

It will just work fine with yarn, but if you are using npm, then you will also need to add this in "scripts" section of your package.json

```
"preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

This will simply use [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) package to fix versions from resolutions.

And then after doing `npm install`, your app should work just fine.

Comment: thanks, man, only adding `"resolutions"` didn't work for me where everyone is talking about. needed this `preinstall` script.

Answer (score 9):

Had this with Styled Components. Resolutions didn't work for me so here's another
solution:

Brute force type casting:

```js
const ThemeProviderFixed = ThemeProvider as unknown as React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{ theme: string }>>;
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I did the same thing to resolve problem. import ReactShadowRoot from 'react-shadow-root';
const ReactShadowRootFixed = ReactShadowRoot as unknown as React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{ children: ReactNode }>>;

Comment: Thank you!! after so many hours of searching, finally a solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

I recently ran into this with a Yarn monorepo where a Typescript create-react-app subproject had `installConfig.hoistingLimits=workspace`. This configuration prevents hoisting of dependencies to the top-level of the monorepo.

When running `react-scripts start`, the type checker was still looking at the top-level `@types` and not finding the matching `@types/react` for the version of React configured on the project. The fix that resolved it was to add the following to the `tsconfig.json` in the subproject:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
},
...
```

This points Typescript at the type definitions that are installed for the specific sub-project.

Comment: This was the only thing that fixed it for me, THANK YOU!

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing as well.

Answer (score 7):

I known issued today

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf yarn.lock
npm install
```

just used npm install sovled problem
but I don't know what happend

Comment: I tried this approach on the project folder once I cloned my repo.  I still get the error.  This seems to be with a handful of libraries and not all of them (with the 2 mentioned above being the main ones).

Do I need to remove the npde_modules globally on my machine to see if that works?  Im not too familiar with the inner workings.  I assumed removing node_modules in the project folders along with what you had above would do the trick but still get that same error.

Comment: Interestingly, I search for solution and ended up with this solution. Every time works...

Comment: You remove the yarn.lock file, but then install the dependencies with npm? Not very consistent, now, is it? ;)

Answer (score 6):

[Sahil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843120/2301092) is correct for npm and yarn, but if you are using pnpm, you need a slightly different setup in your `package.json` file:

```json
"pnpm": {
  "overrides": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38"
  }
}
```

If you are using a monorepo with several packages, this only works at the root `package.json` file of your repo. You can read more about it [here in the pnpm docs.](https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides)

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue, so I updated npm version `^6.0.0 -> 8.0.0` and it was resolved.

Check npm version.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue recently when upgrading to React 18 and forgetting to upgrade my corresponding types in devDependencies.

What worked for me was upgrading React types to match in the package.json file as shown

```json
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "react": "^18.1.0",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I matched the @type/(xxx) versions with the (xxx) versions and it worked. Did it for both react & react-dom. The version that worked for me is 17.0.2 for both of them.

Comment: This solved my problem in a Turborepo monorepo, in which a components package were using a different version of react than an app package.

Answer (score 4):

Ok.  I ended up fixing this problem but to warn you in advance, there wasn't a magical way to do this.

I basically uninstalled all the @types I think were the offenders.  You can find this out by reading your error window.  The key was this message in my original error above.

```
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/user/app/node_modules/@types/react-bootstrap-table-next/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
```

If you see where the node module types are pointing to and its not associated with your library, then remove it.  In my case, my issue was the package TimeAgo and the type error was showing that types were assigned to a different package.  So I uninstalled it and kept cycling through the errors until it went away.

Then I use npm run build to do type checks and instruct me which types I had to reinstall.  (There is probably a better way to do this part but it worked for me even though it was tedious.)

This issue seems to happen when you have a ton of different libraries and their types that have similar dependencies and overtime if they aren't needed, don't do what I do and just keep them piled up in your package.json.

So if you think any type can have conflicts with your library, uninstall and see if the error goes away, and then reinstall if other type errors appear that say the dev type package is missing.  I also had some @type packages as dependencies instead of devDependencies which I removed and moved back into dev.  Don't know if that played a part.

When in doubt, remove all applicable types and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you have older version of npm, just update npm to version > 8.0.0.
It worked for me.

I had npm version 6.x.x. I tried many solutions, but update npm to new version fix this problem easy.

Answer (score 2):

for npm!

check which version of node and npm you have installed.
if you update to 8.x, npm provides you the same thing as resolution does for yarn but its"overrides".
update your package like this:

```
"overrides": {
  "@types/react": "17.x.x",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.x.x"
}
```

my npm and node versions were up to date on local instance, but not on git ci. After the update, it was working without to override the versions for react and react-dom.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately in my case I can't use the most voted answer since I **need** @types18 since I need to use the latest hooks from `react@18` like *useId* and I can't import them using `@types/react@17` since they have no exported members for those hooks.
I was able to use latest types fixing the broken typed deps, thanks to @Chris Web' s answer. For example for the `Redux` Provider:

```
// temp fix due to @types/react@18
const Provider = _Provider as unknown as React.FC<{
  children?: JSX.Element | string;
  store: any;
}>;
```

The `store: any` is not ideal, but it's just a temp fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by following the above solution for react

"resolutions": {
"@types/react": "17.0.2",
"@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},

and for react-native you don't need to add type for react-dom

```
"resolutions": {
"@types/react": "17.0.2",
```

},
After this if you still getting error for react types,
add the type package separetly for react

```
npm install -D @types/react@17.0.2
```

Note - don't add "^" in resolution as it will try to install the latest version of packages which may cause the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

For those who have this type of error in the APP and are using **yarn** instead of **npm**.

## Solution

Just add the to **resolutions** and `preinstall` script inside the `package.json` file and them execute `yarn preinstall` and `yarn`.

- **package.json**

```json
"resolutions": {
    .....
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38"
    ....
  },


"scripts": {
    ......
    "preinstall": "yarn --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts"
    ......
  },
```

### References

- [Source](https://oviniciusfeitosa.gitbook.io/knowledge/technology/programming/programming-languages/javascript/known-issues)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different answer that worked for me (in case the above doesn't work for you). I had a node_modules folder in my user root. So my project folder looked like this:

`~/checkouts/project/node_modules`

but I also had a node_modules folder installed at the user root (probably an accident at some point):

`~/node_modules`

The way npm packages work is it crawls up the directory structure grabbing npm packages along the way. After removing this directory the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on two windows machines one mac and one ubuntu. One win machines was fine (no error on build), the other wind machine gave this error on build. Mac was also fine but ubuntu was also giving this error on build. I was frustrated. Tested with different node versions but that did not help.
In the end had to update some types versions (not sure though if all four needed to be updated but after the update error disappeared):

```
"@types/react": "^16.14.3",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
```

to:

```
"@types/react": "^18.0.15",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.18",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried it in two ways, with yarn's resolution it solved it, but then i deleted my yarn.lock and updated the react's type and it worked for me too without using yarn's resolution

```js
yarn upgrade @types/react@^18.0.21
```

Answer (score -1):

I posted a different answer but it was basically a duplicate answer so I'll provide another approach.

If you're using `yarn`, you can run `yarn dedupe` and it will make the necessary changes to your `yarn.lock` file. It will consolidate any references to the same package to resolve to the correct version. As you can see from here, the `-` lines are what were removed and the `+` line is modified and saved:

```
-"@types/react@npm:*, @types/react@npm:>=15, @types/react@npm:>=16.9.0":
-  version: 17.0.43
-  resolution: "@types/react@npm:17.0.43"
-  dependencies:
-    "@types/prop-types": "*"
-    "@types/scheduler": "*"
-    csstype: ^3.0.2
-  checksum: 981b0993f5b3ea9d3488b8cc883201e8ae47ba7732929f788f450a79fd72829e658080d5084e67caa008e58d989b0abc1d5f36ff0a1cda09315ea3a3c0c9dc11
-  languageName: node
-  linkType: hard
-
-"@types/react@npm:^18.0.0":
+"@types/react@npm:*, @types/react@npm:>=15, @types/react@npm:>=16.9.0, @types/react@npm:^18.0.0":
```

```
"@types/react@npm:*, @types/react@npm:>=15, @types/react@npm:>=16.9.0"
```

was consolidated into

```
"@types/react@npm:*, @types/react@npm:>=15, @types/react@npm:>=16.9.0, @types/react@npm:^18.0.0"
```

Comment: Running `yarn dedupe` returns: 
error The dedupe command isn't necessary. `yarn install` will already dedupe.

Comment: hmm...interesting. I haven't run into that particular error. Which yarn version are you using? We're on 3 with workspaces.

Comment: It looks like `yarn dedupe` was "re-added" into version 2/3?  I'm still on yarn 1 until dependabot works with the recent version

Comment: You can also just manually delete those lines in yarn.lock and reinstall with `yarn install` and the effect should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I put the wrong type of value inside a div.

**Error**

[image]

**Reason**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Fix**

[image]