# React Native monorepo: TS2786: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, dependencies, monorepo

I have a monorepo with the following structure:

```
repo/
├─ node_modules/
├─ package.json
├─ packages/
│  ├─ design-system/
│  │  ├─ package.json // dependencies installed in repo/node_modules
├─ apps/
│  ├─ my-app/
│  │  ├─ node_modules/
│  │  ├─ package.json // dependencies installed in my-app/node_modules
```

repo/packages contains shared packages to be used by various apps in repo/apps. Shared packages have their dependencies in repo/node_modules, managed via Yarn Workspaces in the top level package.json:

```json
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*"
]
```

repo/apps contains React Native apps. Apps in repo/apps have their own local node_modules and are NOT Yarn Workspaces (I decided against that because managing React Native dependencies with Yarn Workspaces was too cumbersome and flaky).

My current workflow is to run `yarn install` in the top level dir, then `cd` into repo/apps/my-app and run `yarn install` to install the local node_modules.

This has been working well, until now...

I have a `design-system` shared package with the following deps:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.67.1"
},
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "0.67.3"
}
```

my-app/package.json has many many dependencies, but I think the relevant one here is:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react-native": "^0.67.1"
}
```

(note how "@types/react": "17.0.2" is NOT a dependency of my-app. I have tried adding it, did not change anything).

When I import it in a component in `my-app`, I get the following error:

```tsx
import { Button } from 'design-system'
import { View } from 'react-native'

const AppComponent = () => (
  <View> // error TS2786
    <Button/>
  </View>
)
```

```
TS2786: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
   Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
     The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
       Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/sam/repo/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

What I understand from this error is that there is a conflict between the `ReactNode` type in the top level node_modules vs the one in the app node_modules.

My question is how and where do i fix this?

- in repo/package.json?
- in design-system/package.json?
- in my-app/package.json?
- in my-app/tsconfig.json?
- somewhere else???

Answer (score 5):

The answer was right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71828113/4876564).

After inspecting my top level yarn.lock, I found that React 18 was indeed making its way into it.

```
"@types/react@*":
  version "18.0.9"
```

I had to add resolutions in the top level package.json:

```json
// repo/package.json

"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
```

Which then changed the lock file to

```
"@types/react@*", "@types/react@17.0.2":
  version "17.0.2"
```

And the errors went away

Comment: Is this still up to date ? Why would you want a typing version under the current version of react ?

Comment: @Dimitri, you should make sure that your `react` version and your `@types/react` version match, otherwise you get all type of strange problems. You can check it by running `yarn why @types/react` and `yarn why react` to see where are your versions coming from. It might be that an external library is adding an unwanted version

Comment: The problem in my case was that two packages in my monorepo were using different versions of react (17 and 18). After I bumped up the 17 to 18 the errors went away