# 'Select.Option' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, antd

I wrote select component using antd select

"react": "^16.9.9",
"antd": "^3.26.17",
"typescript": "4.7.4",

```
 export const SelectComponent = React.forwardRef<any, Props>(
  (
    {
      onChange,
      className,
      loading,
      mode = SelectMode.default,
      showArrow,
      dropdownRender,
      data,
      disabled,
      background,
      border,
      boxShadow,
      color,
      height,
      style,
      showSearch,
      value,
      dropdownStyle,
    }: Props,
    ref
  ) => {
    const wrapperProps = {
      background,
      border,
      boxShadow,
      color,
      height,
      className,
    };

    return (
      <S.Wrapper {...wrapperProps}>
        <Select
          onChange={onChange}
          loading={loading}
          mode={mode}
          showArrow={showArrow}
          className={className}
          value={value}
          dropdownStyle={dropdownStyle}
          dropdownRender={dropdownRender}
          disabled={disabled}
          style={style}
          showSearch={showSearch}
          ref={c => {
            if ((ref as React.RefObject<any>).current)
              (ref as React.RefObject<any>).current.select = c;
          }}
        >
          {data?.map((item: any) => {
            return (
              <Select.Option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                {item.name}
              </Select.Option>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </S.Wrapper>
    );
  }
);
```

During npm run build I got the below error

```
 Type error: 'Select.Option' cannot be used as a JSX component.
          Its instance type 'ClassicComponent<OptionProps, any>' is not a valid JSX element.
            The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
              Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("project-path/node_modules/@types/react-slick/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
                Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        
          59 |           {data?.map((item: any) => {
          60 |             return (
        > 61 |               <Select.Option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
             |                ^
          62 |                 {item.name}
          63 |               </Select.Option>
          64 |             );
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of your `Select` component?

Comment: Where is the `Option` sub-component defined?

Comment: I didn't create any new components I just got the option from select and passed it like below

 {data?.map((item: any) => {
            return (
              <Select.Option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                {item.name}
              </Select.Option>
            );
          })}

@DBS

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NPM package cannot be used as a JSX Component - Type errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791347/npm-package-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-type-errors)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with the old `antd` version. Updating it to `v4` will fix the errors, but it can also break some of your old components, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).