# React18 is not supporting styled-component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.
As I am learning React Native, I was going through styled components but was facing an error related to styled components not compatible with react18 version. and same works in react@16 and below

I was trying to install styled-components for styling components in react-native. And i was receiving error saying that react18 is not compatible. I just want styled components to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM package cannot be used as a JSX Component - Type errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791347/npm-package-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-type-errors)

Comment: @monim Not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the solution as `styled-component` was  not working for react 18.0.2.

So I decided to uninstall react 18.0.2 by using `npm uninstall react@18.0.2`
and then
I reinstalled `npm install react@17.0.2` and then I read the documentation of [Styled Component](https://styled-components.com/)

and installed `styled-components` using `yarn add styled-components` and successfully sorted out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with this command

```
npm install styled-components --force
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npx expo install react-dom
```

This fixed it for me (using expo managed react-native app)

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3788#issuecomment-1335191911

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem when taking Udemy course about React Native. This course provides git with complete code, so what I did was:

- Downloaded packages.json file from git url provided with course (last version),
- Deleted my project node_modules folder,
- Deleted my project packages-lock.json file,
- Executed `npm install`